# Creating basemap from ECW file in ArcGIS .Net Runtime

Tags: ecw, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I'm new to ArcGIS Runtime and all the idea of maps.

I have local ECW map files (UTM projected) on my machine, and I'm trying to understand how I use them as basemaps, so I can draw points on them, get the points when user clicks on the map and etc.

From what I understand, I need to load them as rasters, but this doesn't seem to work,
also I googling this subject doesn't find anything useful...

Does anyone have experience with this?

I'm programming a WPF app, using C#. I tried creating RasterLayer and using this layer as a basemap for my map, But the map doesn't show up.
Here's the code:

```
RasterLayer layer = new RasterLayer(new Raster(map.ecw));
Basemape basemap = new Basemap(layer);
MyMap.Basemap = basemap;
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. A basemap is a service run on a server. Runtime isn't the right tool to publish services (it's more of a service consumer), which is probably why you haven't found any code. Unfortunately, the Focused question/Best answer model used here is not equipped to explain the entire ArcGIS architecture model, the components, the map publishing process, and the map consumption process. We're more of a problem-solving site, where you post a bit of code that's giving you trouble. Also, "Doesn't seem to work" isn't much of a problem statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i'll try be more explicit.
Im programming a WPF app, using c#. 
I tried creating RasterLayer and using this layer as a basemap for my map,
But the map doesn't show up.
Here's the code:
RasterLayer layer = new RasterLayer(new Raster(map.ecw));
Basemape basemap = new Basemap(layer);
MyMap.Basemap = basemap;

Comment: Please don't try to clarify your Question in comments. Instead, [Edit] the Question. Note that these are comments, and that an Answer is one of those large, formattable boxes below.

Comment: @Vince Even the original version of this question makes it clear this is a question about loading raster layers in a basemap. Note sure why you're going down the rabbit hole of talking about publishing services, or trying to tell the user which product he/she should/shouldn't be using. Could the question use a little more context around what the problem is? Sure, but let's be kinder and more welcoming to the users here, rather than trying to pretend to know what they want.

Comment: How did you create the map? Does the map already have a spatial reference established, and does the ECW Layer match that spatial reference? Or does the ECW even have a spatial reference defined? Also try and call "await MyRaster.LoadAsync()" and "await MyLayer.LoadAsync()" and ensure there are no load errors.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Morten.I have got answered in Esri official forum that ECW isn't a supported format.